# MVVM Light not instantiating my ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a Main Silverlight Project, in addition i Have a Silverlight Project for my Views and I have a Silverlight Class Library for my ViewModels.

When designing the view, I can see the ViewModel for the bindings.

In my Main Project in the App, the locator is pointing to my Class Library where the ViewModels are.

When I run my application, my ViewModel is not being instantiated.

What am I missing?

Comment: code. please show us some code

Comment: What does trigger the ViewLocator to be instantiated? or view model to be instantiated

<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        x:Class="PortalProveedores.Client.Views.Seguridad.viewSeguridad"
    DataContext="{Binding SeguridadViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="365" Width="518">

Comment: My App

<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="PortalProveedores.Client.Views.Seguridad.App"              
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PortalProveedores.Client.Views.Seguridad" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />     
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>

Comment: I made it work, the binding is Main, the property of the Locator that expose the ViewModel is the one, I had to write.